# synchronize multiple map reduce jobs in hadoop

Tags: dictionary, hadoop, reduce, synchronize

I have a use case where multiple jobs can run at the same time. The output of all the jobs will have to merged with a common master file in HDFS(containing key value pairs) that has no duplicates. I'm not sure how to avoid the race condition that could crop up in this case. As an example both Job 1 and Job 2 simultaneously write the same value to the master file resulting in duplicates. Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Hadoop doesn't support parallel writing to the same file. Here is the [reference](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.0/hdfs_design.html).

> Files in HDFS are write-once and have strictly one writer at any time.

So, multiple maps/jobs can't write to the same file simultaneously. Another job/shell or any other program has to be written to merge the output of multiple jobs.

Comment: Praveen, I was thinking of using the append feature. Let me know your thoughts on this.